# How to stop receiving my own messages in PubNub

Tags: android, pubnub, satellite

Is there a way for a PubNub client to stop receiving its own messages when it publishes them to a channel that it is also subscribed to? I'm using a very expensive satellite uplink and I want to minimize the amount of data I'm using (it's also very slow at about 2400bps), so I don't want to hear an "echo" (my own messages pushed back to me since I'm also a subscriber).

So is there any way to filter incoming messages and stop them from being pushed to my device? I'm using Android BTW, but the question is generally relevant regardless of the API / language used.

Comment: Hi Razvan good question we'll post an answer today.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Stream Filter: Prevent Receiving Your Own Messages

We have implemented a server-side filtering feature, [Stream Filter](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android/stream-filtering-tutorial-sdk-v4), which you can use to prevent a client that sends a message (publish) from receiving those messages.